# Should I build Node.js from source or download the OS X installer?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'd like to install Node.js on OS X.

You can [build it from source](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation) by cloning the Github repo, or you can [download an installer](http://nodejs.org/download/).

For those who've done Node.js development on OS X, what are the tradeoffs and which option would you recommend?

Comment: Do __you__ want to build Node.js from source or download the OS X installer? The binaries contain everything you need. I for one would choose the installer, since this enables me to jump right onto the node.js development train. Choo choo!

Comment: How has this not been closed yet? Opinion-based much?

Comment: Hey Dave, I actually need an answer to this question. If you don't have anything useful, helpful, or informative to contribute, how bout you just move on. Cool?

Comment: Not really sure why this has close votes. This is a perfectly legit question.

Comment: it's also not opinion-based in the least.

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask: "Some subjective questions are allowed..." [as long as they] 'inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”', "invite sharing experiences over opinions", That's why I included that bits about "for those who've done Node.js development on OS X" and "what are the tradeoffs?"

Comment: He's asking for technical advice on a programming question. He literally asked for tradeoff between each approach. How is that anything like asking, "what's your favorite build method?"

Comment: Also, with 11k rep, maybe he deserves a little leeway. However, I still wouldn't close this if he had 1 rep.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest *not* using the installer, or installing it via `homebrew`, instead use [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to install whatever version of Node you need. That way you are able to fluidly develop in whatever version of node you choose, without having to worry about the headache of conflicting global packages or `$PATH` cruft.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your production environment is OS X, I highly recommend just running a VM that is the same as your production environment.

If you've ever built a non-trivial application in c, you know that cross-platform development is difficult. Different compilers can create different instructions for different architectures and operating systems. This variability can lead to bugs. You should aim to use the same source, same compiler, same operating system, same node.js version and same architecture as your production environment.

Running your own VM as your dev environment will save you a tonne of time on integration issues (especially if there are other developers) and it will encourage you to write a single build script. Again, a critical time saver.

Key points:

- Single build command
- Mirror dev environments to production (reducing differences from compilers, architectures, source versions, etc.)
- Homogenize individual developers dev environments to ease testing and reduce bugs

Comment: This is overkill. I primarily write Node on OSX and I deploy to Windows (Azure) and Linux. I have never had a problem where the app wouldn't work after being deployed. Node is not c, and for the most part doesn't have the same cross platform issues as compiled languages do.

Comment: Node is written in c. So yes, it does have the same issues. Also, he's speaking directly about compilation versus the usage of a precompiled binary. It doesn't take much time to do it properly. And if you want to run anything more significant than a hamster wheel, you'll follow best practices. Launching a software product is hard enough with having to put up with hamstringing yourself out of sheer laziness and ignorance. I think the best advice in software is: break down hard problems into **simple**, composable parts. The more variables you have to deal with, the greater your risk for error.

Comment: Also, many of the node modules have native c code that is also susceptible to cross platform challenges. Only, that is at greater risk because it isn't the node core developers that are ensuring its portability.

Comment: Node being written in C has nothing to do with writing portable apps which run on Node. One of the many advantages that scripting languages offer is the abstraction away from the environment you're deploying on. The vast majority of apps written in PHP or Python or Node don't (and shouldn't) care if they are being run on Windows, OSX or Linux.

Comment: WordPress is a good example. Development on WordPress happens on pretty much every operating system and it runs on pretty much every operating system that will run PHP. I think we can both agree that WordPress is significantly more complicated than a "hamster wheel".

Comment: The fact that a random package runs on many platforms is irrelevant. The point is that writing portable code is harder than only writing for one platform. If you had 10,000 users consuming a product that make sales claims for being supported on two platforms, it would cost more dev hours to ensure that those claims are upheld. PHP, Python or Node will not entirely protect you from this. If you doubt this, check out the Windows-related bug list on php's bug tracker. As with many subjects in computer science, things are more complicated when you scale up.

Comment: WordPress is hardly a random package and runs on literally millions of servers (http://en.wordpress.com/stats/). On top of that there are plenty of major companies and major projects which have developers on different operating systems contributing to a project which runs on multiple operating systems. This is easily doable thanks to the abstraction scripting languages provide. I personally haven't had problems and I know many others who develop the exact same way without issue.

Answer (score 1):

I use the nodejs installer on osx. I see no benefit to building from source unless you actually want to mess with the source. You'll be up and running faster with the installer. They're keeping the binary installer up to date with the respect to the version too so it's not like you can get a later version by building from source.

If you're deploying on some other platform, be careful about installing other binary packages using npm because they might not be available or might have to be rebuilt. I have sometimes made the mistake of copying node_modules binaries from OSX to Windows and of course they don't work. You have to run npm on Windows to get the right binaries for Windows and with complex things like phantomjs you can run into trouble...

Comment: I agree. Use the installer until you run into an issue that requires something other than the installer. YAGNI doesn't just apply to the code you write.